# useState value does not update a new value it just remains the same (I guess it does change for a second but gets back to the default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

> The setvalue() function from the useState() doesn't update the value
> when using setValue() although it feels as if it changed for a second
> and it comes back to the default value please can someone tell what is happening here

**what I am doing here is that I'm just changing the style of the code to bold (only the button that was clicked and then I'm making the style of the code of the other buttons which were not clicked as light (I've implemented this thing in the navbar **

```js
const [value, setvalue] = useState("home");

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("route has been changed");
    var technology = "web";

    // {
    //  matches == true ? (technology = "web") : (technology = "mobile");
    // }

    if (technology == "web") {
        var home = document.getElementById("home");
        var about_us = document.getElementById("aboutus");
        var competitive_programming = document.getElementById("dropdown-basic");
        var blog = document.getElementById("blog");
        if (loggedIn == false) {
            var login = document.getElementById("login");
        }
        console.log("bold value" + boldvalue)
        switch (boldvalue) {
            case "home":
                console.log("hello home");
                home.style.fontWeight = "600";
                about_us.style.fontWeight = "lighter";
                competitive_programming.style.fontWeight = "lighter";
                blog.style.fontWeight = "lighter";
                if (loggedIn == false) {
                    login.style.fontWeight = "lighter";
                }
                break;
            case "aboutus":
                console.log("hello about");
                home.style.fontWeight = "lighter";
                about_us.style.fontWeight = "600";
                competitive_programming.style.fontWeight = "lighter";
                blog.style.fontWeight = "lighter";
                if (loggedIn == false) {
                    login.style.fontWeight = "lighter";
                }
                break;
            case "blog":
                console.log("hello blog");
                home.style.fontWeight = "lighter";
                about_us.style.fontWeight = "lighter";
                competitive_programming.style.fontWeight = "lighter";
                blog.style.fontWeight = "600";
                if (loggedIn == false) {
                    login.style.fontWeight = "lighter";
                }
                console.log("hello blog");
                break;
            case "login":
                console.log("hello login");
                home.style.fontWeight = "lighter";
                about_us.style.fontWeight = "lighter";
                competitive_programming.style.fontWeight = "lighter";
                blog.style.fontWeight = "lighter";
                if (loggedIn == false) {
                    login.style.fontWeight = "600";
                }
                console.log("login style is " + login.style.fontWeight);
                break;
            case "competitive":
                console.log("hello competitive");
                home.style.fontWeight = "lighter";
                about_us.style.fontWeight = "lighter";
                competitive_programming.style.fontWeight = "600";
                blog.style.fontWeight = "lighter";
                if (loggedIn == false) {
                    login.style.fontWeight = "lighter";
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}, [value]);
//this thing executes whenever I click a button
async function SetBolds(e) {
    // var idid = document.getElementById(e.target.id)
    // console.log(e.target.id);
    var idid = e.target.id;
    // I have console.logged the target id its working fine

    switch (idid) {
        case "home":

            setvalue("home");
            break;
        case "aboutus":

            console.log("about us new")
            setvalue("aboutus");

            break;
        case "blog":
            boldvalue = "blog"
            console.log(boldvalue)
            setvalue("blog");
            break;
        case "login":
            boldvalue = "login"
            setvalue("login");
            break;
        case "dropdown-basic":
            boldvalue = "competitive"
            setvalue("competitive");
            break;
        default:
            setvalue("")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why switch-case in SetBolds? just setvalue(idid). Also, it's impossible to tell without knowing more about your code, but it looks like you're always setting technology to web in useEffect, which always runs after a component renders. You shouldn't be manipulating the dom directly in react.

Comment: Hey Charles Bamford Yeah i have done as you have said me to do but still, It doesn't work. What I'm doing here is that I have few buttons in the navbar and when I click any button that button's text should be bold and others should be "lighter" style
Here is the whole code just for your reference 
https://pastebin.com/dbsQKGqf

Comment: If you know any better approach of doing it please let me know (of making the selected text as bold)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/still-sun-brifm?file=/src/App.js Here's how I would do it with a trivial example.

Comment: Thank you really helped a lot although I figured out a different way since that is my navbar I have used `<Navlink  to="/" activeclassname="IsSelected"> </Navlink>`
so what this `activeclassname` attribute does is that whenever a specific route is ON then the Navlink with the same `'to'` route will have the  class 'IsSelected ' attached to it and then its all about adding styling the className, it's actually very help full even you should check it out (if you do not already know about it) 
(https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink)
but btw thanks a lot even that is very helpful

Comment: I'm not using reactrouter, and I don't know how you expected me to know you were. That is part of the important information you should include when you ask a question.

Comment: Since it is a Navbar I thought you would assume that I was using reactrouter but anyways it's what you shared is also very important because without activeclassname I wasn't able to do it but now I think I'll be able to do it